# Car switch ripple noise and regulator

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, automotive

With this circuit I try to convert 12V car battery to 3.3V. When I turn switch multiple time to start motor, high ripple in input happen. Between 6 to 12 V. I used 1000 uF capacitor in input and nothing changed. this cause MCU restart. How can I solve this problem?
MCU:atmega328p

Note1: I add a diode on the input before capacitor .MCU still reset

[image]

Comment: Start by adding a series diode on the input, before the 1000µF input capacitor. Otherwise, the capacitor will just discharge into the starter motor while cranking.

Comment: I add a diode on the input before capacitor .MCU still reset

Comment: @yeganehhp - Hi, That image doesn't show the *real* battery voltage variation due to a starter motor load. Please [edit] your question: (a) Add your scope trace of the 3.3 V rail (i.e. the output of that regulator) at the time when the MCU resets. (Even better, if you have a dual-trace scope, would be for you to provide a single scope capture, showing both the i/p and o/p of the regulator when the MCU resets). (b) Explain how you know that your buck regulator is working properly (e.g. suitable PCB layout, inductor etc.). (c) Add the PCB layout too. (d) Can you add a photo of your h/w? Thanks.

Comment: have you solved this issue? Mine has a similar problem, but I can't add any bulk cap because of space constrain.